# Get pdf file name from a URL in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the pdfname from a URL generating the pdffile....
here is the link

```
$pdflink = "http://example.com/a.php?action=getSubmissionPDF&sid=".$sid."&formID=".$formid;
```

`$pdflink` is having the sid i.e form submission_id... with this sid name of the pdf file is generated

when i click on this url the pdf is generated with the name of `$sid.pdf` like 34556677.pdf

how I got the pdf name from this url??

I want to save this pdf file in infusionsoft filebox..

```
$filename=$_GET['sid'].".pdf";// filename
$contactId=5865;//contactid
$dataEncoded = base64_encode($pdflink);
$uploadFile = $app->uploadFile($filename, $dataEncoded, $contactId);
```

from this code the file is opladed in filebox bt not able to open the file because it shows the file is damaged and error msg it generates

when i download the file from filebox then it displays file is damaged not able to open the file in adobe...

Comment: i want to save this pdf file in filebox in infusionsoft api

Comment: And I want a Porsche... do you want help or do you want people doing it for you ? The latter would probably imply you paying for the service...

Answer (score 0):

use this to get sid value from url $_GET['sid']

Comment: i am getting the sid value bt i want the filename